# How to download the file from remote source and saving it into local folder using Python

Tags: python, django, urllib2

I need one help. I need to download the file from remote source and storing it into local folder using Python. I am explaining my code below.

```
def downloadfile(request):
    """ This function helps to download the file from remote site"""

    if request.method == 'POST':
        URL = request.POST.get('file') #i.e-http://koolfeedback.com/beta/about-us.php
        filename = "status"
        with open(filename,'wb') as fyl:
            fyl.write(urllib2.urlopen(URL).read())
            fyl.close()
```

Here I need to download the page and store into the local `download` folder using `zip` format.Please help me.

Comment: What is `request` here means?

Comment: I have already mention the post data. `request.POST.get('file')=http://koolfeedback.com/beta/about-us.php`. This URL is coming from form parameter and i need to  download that exact page and store it into local folder.

Comment: Looks like you are already saving the content from that URL in a file named "status". Do you want to compact this file using DEFLATE compression and move it to a folder named download?

Comment: yes i need to move it into download folder which is present inside the project directory.

Comment: you are doing `request.POST.get...` but from where the `request` object comes? are you using django?

Comment: Yes, I am using Django.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to use the `urllib` function [`urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) rather than `urlopen`, which is for opening remote files (such as a text file on a remote server you what to read text from, not files you want to download).

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22682/6328995

Comment: No, My main aim is to include the remote file.

Comment: then just link it?

Comment: have you tried: `fyl.write((urllib2.urlopen(URL)).read())` ? the nesting of the functions may be causing the issue. Also, try replacing this line with `print(urllib2.urlopen(URL)).read())` to see if it is actually reading the file properly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django something like this;

```
folder_to_store = "path/to/folder"
full_filename = os.path.join(folder_to_store, request.FILES['file'].name)
fout = open(full_filename, 'wb+')
for chunk in fout.chunks():
    fout.write(chunk)
fout.close()
```